# looking for a good example to create a db record with dapper/sproc

Tags: orm, dapper

Can you point me to a good example for creating a db record with Dapper via sproc? Ideally I would take an OO approach similar to EF like this:

```
var user = new User{ FirstName="John", LastName="Smith"}
var userId = dapper.Create(User);
return userId;
```

Of course, I'm open to the "right" way of doing this in dapper if dapper recommends a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a stored procedure to add a record to the User table like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveUser(@firstName VARCHAR(10),@lastName VARCHAR(10))
AS
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO [User] (FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@firstName ,@lastName);
       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
```

Assuming your User table has Id column (PK) set to Identity.
Now, you can execute your stored procedure like this

```
var conStr="Replace your connection string here";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
   var userId = con.Query<int>("SaveUser", 
                                    new {@firstName = "John", @lastName = "Smith"},
                                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
                              ).First();          
}
```

If you have a class to represent the User table record, you can pass that class object when you call the stored proc.

```
public class UserDto
{
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  public string LastName { set;get;}
}
```

and simply pass the object of this!

```
var conStr="Replace your connection string here";
var u = new UserDto { FirstName = "Johny", LastName= "Depp" };
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
   var userId = con.Query<int>("SaveUser", u, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                   .First();          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at [Drapper](https://github.com/sextondjc/Drapper) (built on top of Dapper) which would allow you to do something like this.

```
// instance of user created somewhere & procedure called
// on repository method.
var user = new User { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
_commander.Execute(user) ? user : null;
```

Assuming you're using a repository class of some sort. I've taken the liberty of fleshing out a bit more code, adding some constructor injection love.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    // the IDbCommander is a Drapper construct
    private readonly IDbCommander _commander;

    public UserRepository(IDbCommander commander)
    {
        _commander = commander;
    }

    public User Create(User user)
    {
        // execute your procedure here (looked up in config)
        return _commander.Execute(user) ? user : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> RetrieveAll()
    {
        return _commander.Query<User>();
    }
}
```

Your SQL code would then be saved in a separate file (json or xml config).

This keeps your C# separate from your SQL making life easier in the long run - changes to your SQL don't involve recompiling your code, your repository class becomes more testable, etc. etc. etc.

```
{
  "Namespaces": [
    {
      "Namespace": "Company.Product.Namespace",
      "ConnectionString": {
          "ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient",
          "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=DrapperTests;Integrated Security=true"
      },      
      "Types": [
        {
          "Name": "Company.Product.Namespace.UserRepository",          
          "Commands": {
              "Create": {
                  "CommandText": "[dbo].[usp_CreateUser]",              
                  "CommandType": 4              
                },
              "RetrieveAll": {
                  "CommandText": "select * from [User];",              
                  "CommandType": 1              
                }
             }
          } 
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```